# Where does Kyogre respawn after beating the Elite Four?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

In Alpha Sapphire I fainted Kyogre in order to carry on with the story (and I forgot to get Pokeballs) and now I've defeated the Elite Four and can't find it anywhere! I've checked the Cave of Origin and the Seafloor Cavern and still can't find it. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Renter the *Cave of Origin*. On the second floor when going down, there is the normal stair-case, as well as another entrance to the west. Take the entrance and keep going downwards that way. You should eventually be able to encounter Kyogre in another room.

See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/200842/87579).